# How to move the customizations done in the Editor to my child theme?

Tags: block-editor, child-theme, theme-twenty-twenty-two, full-site-editing

`Dashboard -> Appearance -> Editor -> 3-dots menu -> Export` lets one download a `zip` file, which contains the folders `parts` and `templates` that - according to various online tutorials - should contain the customizations done with the (Block) Editor.

However, when I move these folders to my twentytwentytwo-child theme and upload it to a new WP instance, the customizations (like for example a Navigation block or a heading I inserted) are missing.

What am I doing wrong?